# Can spot metering at the focus point be enabled on the Olympus PEN-F?

Tags: olympus, spot-metering

Having grown accustomed to dual purpose focus points (spot metering and AF) when using my Nikon DSLR, I'm hoping to use my PEN-F in the same way: meter and focus on the subject and adjust the EV accordingly.

However, right now I'm at a loss on whether the PEN-F offers this flexibility. 
According to the manual, spot metering works as follows:

> Choose this option to meter a small area (about 2% of the frame) with the  camera pointed at the object you wish to meter. Exposure will be adjusted according to the brightness at the metered point

No mention on whether it is the center spot or the selected focus point. Experimenting with the feature suggested the metering area is in the center.

According to this [dpreview.com thread](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3959290), spot metering is available on the PEN-F:

> Pen -F has spot metering at the focus point

Is it possible to use the focus points for spot metering? How is it enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options are available. In the *Custom* menu, there is an option called *Spot Metering* to control this behavior.

On Page 109 of the English manual the option is described as:

> Choose whether the [Spot], [Spot Hilight], and [Spot Shadow] spot
>   metering options meter the selected AF target.